# Selenium Error:I am using selenium webdriver in maximo for testing but some error

Tags: selenium

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (413, 63). Other element would receive the click: <div id="wait" width="100%" height="100%" class="wait" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 666px; width: 1366px; display: block; cursor: wait;">...</div>
          (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
        Command duration or timeout: 94 milliseconds
        Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:52:30 -0700'
        System info: host: 'ICDVM', ip: '10.0.0.11', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
        Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
        Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf), userDataDir=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir16420_7494}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=53.0.2785.143, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
        Session ID: e24f7435d75ad5ddbecb362090ddb0a3
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:631)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:284)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
            at script.Script.main(Script.java:78)
```

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Java != JavaScript. And you can't show us just the error; you'll have to show the code too.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what happened. Did you read it? What does it tell you?

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, there is an element with a `wait` class overlaying the element you are trying to click.

Comment: Pls Check my java Script

Comment: there is none, please update your question with more information (and an actual question)